# Getting Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory when trying to switch Firebase accounts

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I am following this [video](https://youtu.be/P0x0LmiknJc?t=54) and have installed firebase-tools locally for my project. The firebase commands works fine. For example `node_modules/.bin/firebase login:list` gives me the list of the two accounts that i am logged in with. I want to add firebase to my personal flutter project and thats why i want to switch to another account. However, when I type:

```
node_modules/.bin/firebase login:use <my_email>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not determine active Firebase project directory
```

I also have another local installation of the firebase cli in another directory from before and in there i do not have any problems using the cli. But that project already had firebase so i was not the one who initialized firebase there. I am not sure what am I missing.